# Using mod_geoip2 connecting to oracle DB

Tags: apache, geoip

I have configured mod_geoip2 w/apache 2.2.29.
I can load the local DB provided by maxmind(http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/)

Using mod_geoip2, how can i connect to oracle DB to do ip check and restrict users.Seems like there is no option to connect to external DBs?
Any help/info would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

mod_geoip2 does not work with Oracle or any other third party databases. It only works with MaxMind's legacy binary format, such as the [GeoLite Legacy databases](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/).